# Allocate TensorFlow Operations on Main Memory and GPU Memory?

Tags: memory-management, tensorflow, gpu, cpu

Before buying a big graphic card, I want to test a network on a smaller machine
to check its performance and applicability on a computer vision problem I am trying to solve.

I have a notebook with a GTX950M (2GB memory) and 8GB main memory. I estimated the network's memory consumption to be about 2GB (taking into account every operation and variable), so the idea was to outsource most of the operation and variables to the main memory using:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  some_operations()
```

The network fails allocating memory for the gradient, though. Also it relies on operations which are only implemented for the gpu, so using only the cpu won't work...

Is `with tf.device('/cpu:0'): (...)` actually using the main memory or only associating the computation with the cpu?

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: An op also allocates the memory, so if OP is pinned to `cpu:0` it'll use main memory

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavBulatov. I will have another look at my memory estimation, maybe I just messed sth up there. I also did surrond the creation of my TensorFlow variables with `tf.device('/cpu:0')`, this should also put them in the main memory, right? (I use `tf.get_variable(...)`)